# How do you resolve dependencies after installing packages via source?

Tags: rpm, yum

If you downloaded something and compiled via source code, and then you download another package via rpm that requires the thing you downloaded from the source code, how do you make it resolve the dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work... `rpm` maintains its internal database; and knows which rpms and files are installed. It does not know which other files are installed. So either

- install the **something** with an rpm (best uninstall the one you installed from source first)
- when installing your **other** package; tell `rpm` to ignore that dependency; using `--nodeps`. Note that this will make rpm ignore **ALL** dependencies...